# Blueimp File Upload SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: jquery, file-upload, asyncfileupload, blueimp

I just upgraded to the new jQuery (I think I had 1.7, now 1.10.2), which broke the BlueImp File Upload, so I updated the blueImp files.

I am having trouble tracking down a bug I am getting. When I upload a file, it sends an invalid JSON file:

```
{"files":
  [{"name":"jpg.jpg","size":8483,"type":"image\/jpeg","url":"orderfiles\/139\/jpg.jpg","delete_url":"\\/public_html\/uploader\/139\/?file=jpg.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE"}]}
{"files":
 [{"name":"jpg (1).jpg","size":0,"type":"image\/jpeg","error":"abort","delete_url":"\\/public_html\/uploader\/139\/?file=jpg%20%281%29.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE"}]}
```

Which is duplicate with the second entry being empty. The file gets uploaded.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

My code is more or less copied from the source with slight modifications

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
    maxFileSize: 50000000,
    autoUpload: true,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|psd|ai|pdf)$/i,
    process: [
        {
            action: 'load',
            fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png|psd|ai|pdf)$/,
            maxFileSize: 50000000 // 50MB
        },
        {
            action: 'save'
        }
    ]
});
```

Any insight as to why it would be duplicating the JSON data (with the second entry empty)? I can post more parts of code, I'm just not sure which ones are relevant!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you mention what language are you writing, I'm going to bet and say you are using PHP, you might be calling the upload class twice, that was happened to me. Explicitly I was calling it once, but looks like PHP or the framework I was using was calling it for me.

Hope it helps.